# How to assign data filter in lake formation to an iam user using cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, aws-lake-formation, data-filtering

I would like to know how to assign a data filter in lake formation to an Iam user using cloud formation template .
Is this possible at all? I'm pretty new to those, any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Data filter- couldn't find anything really